# How to delete tabs in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Im refactoring the code and want to delete tabs in almost hundred of line. It's python. To illustrate what I want to do here is initial code:

```
def func():
    a = x
    b = z
    f(x)
    # lines of code ...
```

Here I want to get this:

```
a = x
b = z
f(x) 
#lines of code without tabs
```

Is it possible to do it in pycharm cause manually it takes a lot of time?

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + A and type "Reindent" , it should appear no ? Otherwise, you can do the opposite of tab with SHIFT + TAB

Comment: I think getting rid of the function and getting rid of the tab isn't something that PyCharm is going to do automatically for you. You could write some code that removes all functions and tabs for anything indented. That being said, why do you want to get rid of the function? You can of course do what you want, but usually functions are more readable than 1 file filled with 100 lines of code. If this is just about one file you can remove the functions yourself and use shift + tab on all lines as @rak007 mentioned.

Comment: I don't think you want to remove the tabs. Python uses tabs to figure out scope.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ignoring your function issue that others have mentioned in the comments, unindenting/untabbing many lines of code can be done in PyCharm by highlighting the text and pressing `shift + tab`.

For interest, highlighting and pressing `tab` alone, adds a tab/indent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a tab there is an easy manual way how you can do it:

Ctrl + Shift + A and then search Delete. That is all.